# How to catch CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

When this section of code is executed

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

The `try` `catch` block doesn't handle the `exception`.

```
    public EnumerableObservable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        this.enumerable = enumerable;
        this.cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.cancellationToken = cancellationSource.Token;


        this.workerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var value in this.enumerable)
                {
                    //if task cancellation triggers, raise the proper exception
                    //to stop task execution

                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    foreach (var observer in observerList)
                    {
                        observer.OnNext(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.ToString());                    
            }
        }, this.cancellationToken);

    }
```

Comment: Catch `OperationCanceledException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AggregateExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx) are thrown when a possible multitude of exceptions during asynchronous operations occured. They contain all exceptions that were raised e.g. in chained [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) (via .[ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)) or within cascaded [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/mt674882.aspx) calls.

As @Mitch Stewart pointed out, the correct exception-type to handle would be [OperationCancelledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in your example.

Comment: Actually, the exception way is better to do, if you use the exception it will make `workerTask.IsCanceled == true`  if the token that raised the exception is the same token you passed in to the `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`

Comment: sure, but with graceful cancellation, one gains more control over the actual termination of the asynchronous execution.

there are many good reasons why the TPL-development team implemented Cancellatio-infrastructure in the first place, as the former Thread-Model did not supply such mechanisms per default.
See also this post from back 2004 about [why Thread.Abort is evil](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation)

Comment: I don't understand your comment. using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` [is considered graceful cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx). Not shure why you brought up Thread.Abort.

Comment: yeah, I see your point know. I think I mixed concepts / terms here, nevermind. Will remove the part that suggests the polling approach ;).
And thx for pushing my mind in the right direction ;)
Thread.Abort really was kind of off Topic, though.

Comment: Neither chained tasks nor cascaded async/await calls will cause an `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 2):

Since ThrowIfCancellationRequested() throws an exception of type OperationCanceledException, you must catch OperationCanceledException or one of its base classes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception(v=vs.110).aspx